# poor hadoop performance in word count - scheduling issues

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am running a 16 node hadoop cluster on ec2 with m1.large machines. I am facing performance problems because of foolish scheduling that hadoop is doing. I am using hadoop-2.2.0 with yarn.

The exact problem is the following:

I am running the wordcount program on the cluster. There is 4GB of entire data on which wordcount needs to be done. I am currently trying with 4 reducers. Unfortunately all the 4 reducers are getting scheduled on the same machine which really makes the performance poor. Is there some way I can avoid this. Is there some scheduling policy which will better load balance the reduce tasks.

PS: I understand hadoop is not meant for high performance, but I have to benchmark certain map reduce programs and the effect of poor scheduling will greatly effect my benchmarks.

Thanks

Comment: The problems arise, because the wordcount example is super inefficient. Although I can't imagine that a m1.large instance is overloaded with just four reducers. What is the bottleneck in your case? IO?

Comment: Amazon recommends to configure max 2 reducers that can be run simultaneously http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/TaskConfiguration.html . Thus the poor performance.